# Python regular expression (regex) match comma separated number - why does this not work?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse transaction letters from my (German) bank.
I'd like to extract all the numbers from the following string which turns out to be harder than I thought.
Option 2 does almost what I want. I now want to modify it to capture e.g. 80 as well.

My first try is option 1 which only returns garbage. Why is it returning so many empty strings? It should always have at least a number from the first \d+, no?

Option 3 works (or at least works as expected), so somehow I am answering my own question. I guess I'm mostly banging my head about why option 2 does not work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re


my_str = """
Dividendengutschrift für inländische Wertpapiere

Depotinhaber    : ME

Extag           :  18.04.2013          Bruttodividende
Zahlungstag     :  18.04.2013          pro Stück       :       0,9800 EUR
Valuta          :  18.04.2013

                                       Bruttodividende :        78,40 EUR
                                      *Einbeh. Steuer  :        20,67 EUR
                                       Nettodividende  :        78,40 EUR

                                       Endbetrag       :        57,73 EUR
"""

print re.findall(r'\d+(,\d+)?', my_str)
print re.findall(r'\d+,\d+', my_str)
print re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*,\d+|\d+', my_str)
```

Output is

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', ',98', '', '', '', '', ',40', ',67', ',40', ',73']
['0,9800', '78,40', '20,67', '78,40', '57,73']
['18', '04', '2013', '18', '04', '2013', '0,9800', '18', '04', '2013', '78,40', '20,67', '78,40', '57,73']
```

Comment: Could you not make use of the strict date/price formats?
`prices = re.findall(r"(\d+,\d+) EUR", my_str)`
`dates = re.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)", my_str)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Option 1 is the most suitable of the regex, but it is not working correctly because `findall` will return what is matched by the capture group `()`, not the complete match.

For example, the first three matches in your example will be the `18`, `04` and `2013`, and in each case the capture group will be unmatched so an empty string will be added to the results list.

The solution is to make the group non-capturing

```
r'\d+(?:,\d+)?'
```

Option 2 does not work only so far as it won't match sequences that don't contain a comma.

Option 3 isn't great because it will match e.g. `+,1`.

Answer (score 10):

> I'd like to extract all the numbers from the following string ...

By "numbers", if you mean both the currency amounts AND the dates, I think that this will do what you want:

```
print re.findall(r'[0-9][0-9,.]+', my_str)
```

Output:

```
['18.04.2013', '18.04.2013', '0,9800', '18.04.2013', '78,40', '20,67', '78,40', '57,73']
```

If by "numbers" you mean only the currency amounts, then use

```
print re.findall(r'[0-9]+,[0-9]+', my_str)
```

Or perhaps better yet,

```
print re.findall(r'[0-9]+,[0-9]+ EUR', my_str)
```

Comment: r”\d+” also works

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, which parse the statement and put the result in a dictionary called `bank_statement`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import itertools

my_str = """
Dividendengutschrift für inländische Wertpapiere

Depotinhaber    : ME

Extag           :  18.04.2013          Bruttodividende
Zahlungstag     :  18.04.2013          pro Stück       :       0,9800 EUR
Valuta          :  18.04.2013

                                       Bruttodividende :        78,40 EUR
                                      *Einbeh. Steuer  :        20,67 EUR
                                       Nettodividende  :        78,40 EUR

                                       Endbetrag       :        57,73 EUR
"""

bank_statement = {}

for line in my_str.split('\n'):
    tokens = line.split()
    #print tokens


    it = iter(tokens)
    category = ''
    for token in it:
        if token == ':':
            category = category.strip(' *')
            bank_statement[category] = next(it)
            category = ''
        else:
            category += ' ' + token

# bank_statement now has all the values
print '\n'.join('{0:.<18} {1}'.format(k, v) \
                for k, v in sorted(bank_statement.items()))
```

The Output of this code:

```
Bruttodividende... 78,40  
Depotinhaber...... ME  
Einbeh. Steuer.... 20,67  
Endbetrag......... 57,73  
Extag............. 18.04.2013  
Nettodividende.... 78,40  
Valuta............ 18.04.2013  
Zahlungstag....... 18.04.2013  
pro Stück........ 0,9800
```

#### Discussion

- The code scans the statement string line by line
- It then breaks each line into tokens
- Scanning through the tokens and look for the colon. If found, use the part before the colon as category, and the part after that as value. `bank_statement['Extag']` for example, has the value of *'18.04.2013'*
- Please note that all the values are strings, not number, but it is trivia to convert them.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000960/python-regular-expressions-re-search-vs-re-findall) is relevant; the following

```
print re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)?', my_str)
                       ^^
```

ouputs

```
['18', '04', '2013', '18', '04', '2013', '0,9800', '18', '04', '2013', '78,40', '20,67', '78,40', '57,73']
```

Excluding the "dotted" numbers is a little more complicated:

```
print re.findall(r'(?<!\d\.)\b\d+(?:,\d+)?\b(?!\.\d)', my_str)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This outputs

```
['0,9800', '78,40', '20,67', '78,40', '57,73']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
re.findall(r'\d+(?:[\d,.]*\d)', my_str)
```

This regex requires that the match at least starts with a number, then any amount of a mix of numbers, comma's and periods, and then it should end with a number too.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 doesn't match numbers like '18.04.2013' because you are matching '\d+,\d+' which means

digit (one or more) comma digit (one or more)

For parsing digits in your case I'll use

```
\s(\d+[^\s]+)
```

which translates to

```
space (get digit [one or more] get everything != space)

space = \s
get digit = \d
one or more = + (so it becomes \d+)
get everything != space = [^\s]
one or more = + (so it becomes [^\s]+
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with out non-capturing group

`re.findall(r'(?<!\.)\b\d+[,\d]*\d\b(?!\.)', my_str)`

1. `(?<!\.)` - Check if there is no `.` before any number. (To
   avoid '2013' in date 18.04.2013)
2. `\b\d+` - number should be the start of the word string
3. `[,\d]*` - consider comma or number
4. `\d\b` - number should be the end of the word string
5. `(?!\.)` - Check if there is no `.` after any number. (To
   avoid '18' or '04' in date 18.04.2013)